# При запуске русской конфигурации MyCompany lsfusion сервер падает

Tags: lsfusion

Сервер Lsfusion 5.1  с конфигурацией MyCompany при указании в settings.properties
`logics.topModule = MyCompanyRu` падает через несколько сенунд со следующими ошибками в start.log:

```
27 Oct 2023 15:39:14,387 ERROR StartLogger - Exception while starting logics instance:
Error during parsing at : SUZLotOrder(111:17↕)
java.lang.RuntimeException: lsfusion.server.language.ScriptingErrorLog$SemanticErrorException: [error]: SUZLotOrder:83: @defineDocStatusForm(doc=lotOrder, let=o)
                        Doc:103:        @defineDocStatusForm(doc=lotOrder, let=o, beforeProp=nameType)
                        Doc:70:17 component 'filters' is not found
Subsequent errors (if any) could not be found.
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
        at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptParser.lambda$0(ScriptParser.java:108)
        at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptParser.runCode(ScriptParser.java:141)
        at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptParser.runMetaCode(ScriptParser.java:73)
        at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptingLogicsModule.runMetaCode(ScriptingLogicsModule.java:4045)
        at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.metaCodeStatement(LsfLogicsParser.java:38543)
        at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.statement(LsfLogicsParser.java:1043)
        at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.statements(LsfLogicsParser.java:706)
        at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.metaCodeParsingStatement(LsfLogicsParser.java:1089)
        at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptParser.lambda$0(ScriptParser.java:87)
        at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptParser.runCode(ScriptParser.java:141)
        at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptParser.runMetaCode(ScriptParser.java:73)
        at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptingLogicsModule.runMetaCode(ScriptingLogicsModule.java:4045)
        at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.metaCodeStatement(LsfLogicsParser.java:38543)
        at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.statement(LsfLogicsParser.java:1043)
        at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.statements(LsfLogicsParser.java:706)
        at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.script(LsfLogicsParser.java:660)
        at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptParser.initParseStep(ScriptParser.java:61)
        at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptingLogicsModule.parseStep(ScriptingLogicsModule.java:5284)
        at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptingLogicsModule.initMainLogic(ScriptingLogicsModule.java:244)
        at lsfusion.server.logics.controller.init.InitMainLogicTask.runInnerTask(InitMainLogicTask.java:28)
        at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptingLogicsModule.runInit(ScriptingLogicsModule.java:303)
        at lsfusion.server.physics.dev.module.controller.init.GroupModuleTask.runTask(GroupModuleTask.java:20)
        at lsfusion.server.physics.dev.module.controller.init.GroupModuleTask.runTask(GroupModuleTask.java:1)
        at lsfusion.server.base.task.GroupSingleTask$1.run(GroupSingleTask.java:67)
        at lsfusion.server.base.task.Task.proceed(Task.java:154)
        at lsfusion.server.base.task.Task$1.aspectRun(Task.java:112)
        at lsfusion.server.base.controller.thread.ExecutorFactory$AspectRunnable.run(ExecutorFactory.java:475)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at lsfusion.server.base.controller.thread.ExecutorFactory$ClosableDaemonThreadFactory$ClosableThread.run(ExecutorFactory.java:554)
Caused by: lsfusion.server.language.ScriptingErrorLog$SemanticErrorException: [error]:  SUZLotOrder:83: @defineDocStatusForm(doc=lotOrder, let=o)
                        Doc:103:        @defineDocStatusForm(doc=lotOrder, let=o, beforeProp=nameType)
                        Doc:70:17 component 'filters' is not found
```

Если же указать `logics.topModule = MyCompany` то версия на английском страрует и работает нормально.
Было проверено с сервером на debian 11 и на хосте с windows, результат одинаков.

Answer (score 1):

В определенной версии собранного jar-файла MyCompany была ошибка для русской версии. В последней версии ее уже не должно быть.

Необходимо скачать последнюю версию по адресу : https://download.lsfusion.org/solutions/mycompany-1.0.jar. Затем заместить старый jar-файл скачанным в каталоге /var/lib/lsfusion для Linux или C:\Program Files\lsFusion 5\Server\lib для Windows. После этого перезапустить службу. Ошибка должна исчезнуть после этого.